# command in /etc/inittab is not working on SLES 11

Tags: boot, init.d, sles, sysvinit

My task is to start a process on startup if it was running before shutdown. To achieve this, I have added a command in `/etc/init.d/halt.local` to save the state of process in a file.

In `/etc/inittab`, I added command to read file and start the process based on state recorded. But the process is not coming up. I can see that the state was recorded properly while shutdown, and also few other commands I added to /etc/inittab which are executing properly, but not the one needed.

Content added to inittab:

```
ec1:235:once:/bin/echo "Started..." > /tmp/pankaj3.txt
rly:235:once:/bin/su - user -c '[[ `head -1 /tmp/pankaj/.status` == STARTED ]] && { /opt/my_user/bin/ctrl.sh start ; }'
```

On executing the command on terminal, its working fine. The output is:

```
SS-01:~ # /bin/su - user -c '[[ `head -1 /tmp/pankaj/.status` == STARTED ]] && { /opt/my_user/bin/ctrl.sh start ; }'
[07-10-2015] 10:33:00 ctrl.sh[18008]: Management Process started.
```

The other line added to inittab `ec1:235:once:/bin/echo "Started..." > /tmp/pankaj3.txt` is executed.

Please help me to get where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Possibly an environmental issue; compare the output of printenv in working and non-working situations.

Comment: How do you know /tmp is mounted when your command is being run when you enter level 2? or 3?. IMO this is not the way to go, if you want to start a process you should do it creating a script in /etc/init.d and linking that script to the right run level directory (/etc/init.d/rc0.d, rc1.d, etc...) if you are running a sysinit system, if instead it is a systemd or upstart you will need to check how it is done in those.

Comment: You have to be specific about what you mean by "unix", because on a lot of operating systems (both Unices and Unix-alikes) [there's a good reason that things in /etc/inittab have no effect](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  *Tell people in your question* what operating system this is.  Then they'll know what the likely semantics of `/tmp` are, for starters.  They'll still tell you that an asymmetric design that has half of the task done by an `init`-spawned process and the other half by an `rc` subscript is a poor one, though. ☺

Comment: @JdeBP...I am using `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)`. Also, I tried by modifying the command as `rly:235:once:/bin/su - user -c '/opt/my_user/bin/ctrl.sh start'`, and it executed. But not sure why a condition it is not accepting.

Comment: Is perhaps `systemd` being used instead of the old SystemV init? Is `/sbin/init` a symlink and if so where is it pointing to?

Comment: @wurtel...`/sbin/init` is not a symlink

Comment: dividing your functionality between `inittab` started process and `rc` subprocess does not sound good. I would put all this functionality in your `rc` script extending it, check the existence of the status file and execute the program if it was `STARTED`, and overwrite its contents with the new status at shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like SUSE Linux ES 11 uses the traditional System V init system (sysvinit).  [Suse Doc | The init Process](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_boot_init.html)

You can see [man inittab(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=inittab&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SuSE+Linux%2Fi386+ES+10+SP1&arch=default&format=html) for documentation of the syntax.

Firstly, it could be that `inittab` doesn't support shell features such as redirection and compound commands, which are only supported in the shell.  Altho you say your first command works, which suggests that's not the reason.

Secondly, `su` runs `/bin/sh` by default, which might not support `[[`.

Thirdly, files in `/tmp` are usually deleted during boot, so if you created `/tmp/pankaj/.status` during shut down, it's almost certainly not there after rebooting.  Check if that file is present.

In any case, you should make it a separate init script that uses your expected shell as the `#!` line, put it in `/etc/init.d/pankaj` (or whatever), and make it run at levels 2, 3, and 5 with `chkconfig`.

The [Init Scripts section of the SUSE Administration Guide](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_boot_init.html#sec_boot_init_skripte) provides some tips for getting started with that.

Lastly, if all you're trying to do is make a service restart on boot if it was previously running, then don't.  `chkconfig` is the standard tool for configuring something to start at boot.  It's what every other service on your system uses.  Making one service act differently will just confuse things.